# Power BI - rankx with filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've been struggling with this and hope someone is able to help...

I have a table with sales for products over multiple years.  There is a measure that gives me the total revenue for each year by customer, ignoring product sold:

```
totalRevenueMeasure =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( test[Revenue] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( test, test[company], test[year] )
)
```

```
Year    company     Product    revenue  totalRevenueMeasure     rankx (revenue in year)
2018    company a   shoes       100             300               1
2018    company a   mugs        200             300               1
2018    Company b   shoes       250             250               2
2019    company a   lamps       300             300               2
2019    Company b   shoes       350             450               1
2019    Company b   mugs        100             450               1
2019    Company c   mugs        100             100               3
2020    company a   shoes       150             150               2
2020    Company c   lamps       200             200               1
```

The closest I got to the RANKX measure is below but this doesn't give the correct results.  The expected output is in the RANKX column of the table above.

```
Customer Rank = 
          RANKX(
                ALLSELECTED( test[company],test[year]),               
                [TotalRevenueMeasure],
                , 
                DESC,
                Dense 
          )
```

Thanks in advance for pointers, DAX is still eluding me a bit and there might be a better way to go about it.

---

Following the recommendation from Alexis, success with test data but live skips some rows in rank - year 2019 doesn't have a rank #1 but has 2 rank #2.  I guess this must be some kind of data issue...

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: If the data type you are using is Decimal, try to cast the result to Currency in the RANKX.
https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2014/07/16/use-of-rankx-with-decimal-numbers-in-dax/

Comment: This worked perfectly.. I would have been hunting hours for that.. thank you!

Comment: I did actually hunt for hours for a similar issue a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. The problem is that you are looking to rank each year separately but you've removed the `Year` filter context with your ALLSELECTED function.

Take out the second argument in ALLSELECTED so that you only have `company` (since you don't actually want to rank over all years for each row).

Comment: Thanks Alexis, this works for the test data set.  Annoyingly, when used on the live it skips some rankings.  I've edited the main question with a screenshot of how this ranks.